# conversion parse profile JSON java to c#

Tags: java, c#, json

I found the library **Newtonsoft.Json;** which offers a lot of possibilities with JSON objects but I cannot parse a Jarray from a JSON file**?
 Sample JSON file:

{"0": [-12.770680147058824, 1.846047794117647, -54.265625, 55.77863587895704], "1": [-18.388229927007298, 6.5360401459854014, -52.65647810218978, 56.156491225545878], "2": [-20.042738970588236, 12.849264705882353, -46.678308823529413, 52.399231898471129], "3": [-38.242244525547449, 15.836222627737227, -40.48357664233577, 57.897972254845804], "4": [-33.016879562043798, 6.3001824817518246, -38.179288321167881, 50.867127813832226], "5": [-31.816605839416059, 4.7130474452554747, -33.626824817518248, 46.532489409766747]

Comment: Please clarify what it is that you are trying to do, and ignore the code you had in a prior language. You really want to ask: "How can I parse an array from a JSON document using C#"

Comment: Is this enough to get you started? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197957(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Yes in fact I want to parse a Jarray from a JSON file

Comment: please add a sample jason

Comment: That sample JSON you provided is not valid JSON, as you are missing a '}' at the end. Also, that content should be parsed to a JObject, because it isn't an array. It does however, contain multiple JArrays

Comment: Yes because it is a too long file so I just took an extract. Sorry for the missing '}'... In fact I want to parse the JArrays.

Comment: I'd suggest letting us know what you have tried so we can point you in the right direction

Comment: @austin I've tried this:
 JArray nameArray = JArray.Parse(the_json);
But I am not sure if it gives the arrays of the JSON..

Comment: I have already stated that your JSON is not a valid JArray... It is a JObject that contains JArray's... `var jObject = JObject.Parse(the_json);` should work just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample JSON you provided is not a `JArray`. However, you can parse that JSON to a `JObject` and get the JArray's separately.

`var jObject = JObject.Parse(the_json);` will get you a `JObject` reflecting your JSON string.

```
    var jObject = JObject.Parse(@"{""0"": [-12.770680147058824, 1.846047794117647, -54.265625, 55.77863587895704], ""1"": [-18.388229927007298, 6.5360401459854014, -52.65647810218978, 56.156491225545878], ""2"": [-20.042738970588236, 12.849264705882353, -46.678308823529413, 52.399231898471129], ""3"": [-38.242244525547449, 15.836222627737227, -40.48357664233577, 57.897972254845804], ""4"": [-33.016879562043798, 6.3001824817518246, -38.179288321167881, 50.867127813832226], ""5"": [-31.816605839416059, 4.7130474452554747, -33.626824817518248, 46.532489409766747]}");
    foreach (var property in jObject.Properties())
    {
        var array = property.Value as JArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just parse this JSON into a `Dictionary<string, List<double>>`:

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<double>>>(yourJson);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/W6ODpE